# My desktop PC wont start anymore. What can be?

Tags: hardware-failure

My PC is a desktop Amd Ryzen 5 1600.
If I press turn on button, nothing happen (no hard disk movement, no cpu fan movement)..it's like electric not arrive.
I already try

1. Change power supply with a brand new
2. Change mainboard with a brand new
3. Unplug external graphic card
4. Unplug 2 hard drive
5. unplug 2 ram , one at time
6. To exclude power button problem, i try to power on pc using a screwdrive on power pin on mainboard
7. The only thing I haven't change is CPU

There is a led in the new mainboard (a320m-k), that turn on as soon as I plug power wire.. so i think electric power isn't an issue.

So, if I press power button nothing happens, not even the hard drives movement or the CPU fan.
What could be the problem?

Comment: `The only thing I haven't change is CPU` - I think you've nailed it

Comment: there's quite often error LEDs - asus is good about them, might be a useful bit of  troubleshooting information

Comment: Have you followed the correct ESD protocols? If not then you could have fried anything & everything.

Comment: What might have caused the issue? Was it working and broke in middle of use? Was it after OS update? After shutting down? Something else?